# dynamically add divs after div

Tags: html, jquery

I have found some questions which tackle a similar problem, however I can't get my head around on how to change my code so it would work.

I have a div that immitates a table and subdivs that immitate rows,
first row with data inserted is no problem, but i don't know how to change my 'pointer'(do not know the right word) to the next "row"-div when creating a new one and add data to that specific div.

**JQuery:**

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    var e = document.getElementById("lineDesc");
    var line = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var month = document.getElementById("descMonth").value;
    var desc = $("#lineDescAr").val();
    var search = document.getElementById("searchtab");
    let fd = new FormData();
        fd.set('line', line);
        fd.set('month', month);
        fd.set('desc', desc);
    var x=0; //here im trying to create a counter
    fetch('search.php',{method:'POST',body: fd})
        .then( r=> r.json())
        .then( json=>{
            search.innerHTML="";
            Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
            let obj=json[ key ];
            var description = obj.description;
            //new divs that imitate data in row-cells
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.line+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.scanner+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.fault+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.duration+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.date+'</div>';
            //add new dynamic div after row-div
            search.after('<div class="row" id="search'+x+'"></div>');
            //change content of search to new dynamic div
            search = document.getElementById("search"+x);
            console.log(search);
            //increase counter
            x+=1;
            })
        })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I am trying to change the content of search to the new div which should have the `id="search[0-z]"` as however many divs are needed in the loop.

The solution to use node with `.insertBefore()` has helped, but to no avail.

**EDIT:** Use of .after() was completely wrong.

Comment: You seem to be using mostly vanilla JavaScript. Maybe you can get rid of jQuery completely if you replaced the two places where you are looking for an element with an Id by something like `document.getElementById(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the insertion of new divs to createElement and add id and className, .after() cannot convert a given string into an element as it just outputs it as a string.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "search"+x;
newDiv.className = "row";

search.after(newDiv);
search = document.getElementById(newDiv.id);
x+=1;
```

for anyone interested in the full code:

```
$("#search").click(function(event){
    var e = document.getElementById("lineDesc");
    var line = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var month = document.getElementById("descMonth").value;
    var desc = $("#lineDescAr").val();
    var search = document.getElementById("searchtab");
    let fd = new FormData();
        fd.set('line', line);
        fd.set('month', month);
        fd.set('desc', desc);
    var x=0;
    fetch('search.php',{method:'POST',body: fd})
        .then( r=> r.json())
        .then( json=>{
            search.innerHTML="";
            Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
            let obj=json[ key ];
            var description = obj.description;
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.id = "search"+x;
            newDiv.className = "row";
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.line+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.scanner+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.fault+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.duration+'</div>';
            search.innerHTML +='<div class="cell" onclick=\'showDesc(\"'+description+'\")\'>'+obj.date+'</div>';
            search.after(newDiv);
            search = document.getElementById(newDiv.id);
            console.log(search);
            x+=1;
            })
        })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```